# Is it correct that $ \sum_{i=m}^na=(nm+1)a$

Tags: summation

I study this in a book. Is it correct? Why?
$$ \sum_{i=m}^na=(nm+1)a$$

Comment: Which book? $ $

Comment: One more typo !

Answer (score 4):

Of course this is wrong (try $n=m$). The factor in parentheses should be $n-m+1$. And even then this is only valid if $n\geq m-1$ (or $a=0$).

Comment: It should still be fine for $n<m-1$: $\sum_{i=m}^n a = -\sum_{j=n+1}^{m-1} a$

Comment: @you-sir-33433: No, the usual convention for summations is that if the summation range contains no integers, then the sum is $0$. It is true that for integrals one usually defines the integral in the reverse direction to be minus the corresponding forward integral, and something similar _can_ be done for simple summations; however one usually takes the _set_ of valid indices as basis for the definition, rather than counting indices that are excluded by both bound conditions with weight $-1$. I think the latter convention would become rather difficult to maintain for multiple summations.

Comment: Strange, I have never heard of this convention.  I don't really see any advantages to handling sums differently from integrals, especially when it breaks so many formulas and basic algebraic properties (e.g. $\sum_{a}^b + \sum_{b+1}^c = \sum_a^c$).

Answer (score 0):

The result is incorrect. $\sum_{i=m}^na=(nm+1)a$ for $n=m$ results in $(m^2+1)a$ but it should actually give you $a$.
$\sum_{i=m}^na=a+a(n-m)=a(n-m+1)$ $[n\ge m-1]$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{i=m}^na=a\sum_{i=m}^n1=a\sum_{i=m}^n\frac{i}{i}=a\left(\frac{m}{m}+\frac{m+1}{m+1}+\cdots+\frac{n}{n}\right)=a(n-m+1)$$

EDIT:

From definition
$$\sum_{i=m}^na_i=a_m+a_{m+1}+...+a_n$$

for $a_n=...=a_m=a$
follow that
$$\sum_{i=m}^na=a(n-m+1)$$

Comment: Is there any particular reason to disguise $1$ as $\frac ii$? Especially since $m\leq0\leq n$ is allowed, so $i$ could be $0$.

Comment: I find it strangely captivating.  A joke maybe?

Comment: Since $i$ is muted index $\sum_{i=m}^{n}1=\sum_{j=m}^{n}1$ we can write something like that. How you would explain why $\sum_{i=m}^{n}1=n-m+1$

Comment: @AdiDani Because $n-m+1$ is exactly what we write when we mean "add $1$ to itself $n-m+1$ times"?  How would you explain why $\frac{m}{m} + \frac{m+1}{m+1} + \cdots + \frac{n}{n} = n-m+1$?

Comment: $\frac{m}{m}+\cdots+\frac{n}{n}$ is farther away from the answer $n-m+1$ than the original expression $1+\cdots+1$ is. There is literally no point to it, it serves only to distract and mislead. This is why I downvoted this answer.